# rowsRemoved event handler called once

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I am working with a C# Software in Windows Form in which I have a datagridView where the user can delete rows.

I would like to capture the event of deleting rows at once and the problem is that the event handler RowsRemoved is called once per deleted row. In the Msdn stays that e, the event Argument contains the number of rows that have been deleted but when debugging I see that this number is always 1.

What can I do in order to call this event only when the last row of the selected rows has been deleted and with the total of deleted rows?

Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the group of rows is deleted the number of selected rows is 0 or 1 if the row "new row" is selected:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Row deleted");
        if ((dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count==0)
            || ((dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            &&(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].IsNewRow)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Set of rows deleted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for this. Wouldn't mind a bit of an explanation though... (also you should accept this answer even though it's yours so that it appears on the top)

Comment: Thanks. I did not get that about "accept this answer". Now its done! Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use logic to detect whether it's the last row. It even deletes per row when you delete a whole block of rows?

```
void dgv_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == (dgv.RowCount - e.RowCount))
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi MrFox, I didn't formulate my question correctly. What I meant is that I want to catch the event only once and not once per row. With "last row" I wanted to say "last selected row" and not last row in the datagridview... Anyway, your answer has given me an idea that I will post as answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fleve Please reformat your question to be clear and useful for others.